# Аналог функции dpois (язык R) в python (распределение Пуассона)

Tags: python, r, numpy, scipy

В языке R имеется функция `dpois` для вычисления распределения Пуассона, которой, в качестве операндов, передается некая `lambda` (вещественное число), и вектор неких неотрицательных квантилей.

Предположим, что мне необходимо вычислить распределение для `lambda=1.435678`, вектор от `0` до `4`.

В `R` это будет выглядеть так:

```
dpois(x=(0:4), lambda=1.435678)

[1] 0.23795398 0.34162529 0.24523196 0.11735804 0.04212209
```

Вопрос в следующем - с помощью какого модуля в python можно получить такой же результат?

Пробовал через `numpy.random.poisson`, но получил что-то не то:

```
from numpy.random import poisson as poi

print poi(1.435678, 4)

>>> [1 4 1 1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numpy.random.poisson` - это аналог `rpois()` в R, т.е. генератор случайных чисел.

`dpois()` вычисляет значения плотности распределения (или, точнее, Probability Mass Function). В Python:

```
scipy.stats.poisson.pmf(k, mu, loc)
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html

http://www.astroml.org/book_figures/chapter3/fig_poisson_distribution.html

Comment: замечательно, то, что нужно. Спасибо